# How to query ActiveRecord for 2 attributes with 1 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a username in this variable `invoice.user_name`, say `John Wayne Doe`. I want to find a User based on his/her name. Ideally, I would like to use User.where(name: invoice.user_name). However, my database has 'first_name' and 'last_name', so I can't query based on `name`. Would it be possible to do something like this: `User.where('first_name AND last_name like ?', invoice.user_name')`

Or how would I approach that?

Thx

Comment: I don't think identifying invoice's user this way is a good idea at all - full name doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: I don't disagree. Will work in this case though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way... or at least it works for me using a postgreSQL database...

```
User.where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = ?", invoice.user_name)
```